# Is there a high level http node module that supports what 'curl --negotiate' does?

Tags: node.js, rest, authentication

I am searching for a Node module to make REST requests. I found the [Request](https://github.com/request/request) module which looks popular, but It doesn't seem to mention whether it can do authentication with negotiation.  I need to emulate what curl is doing with its --negotiate flag:

```
--negotiate

(HTTP) Enables Negotiate (SPNEGO) authentication.
```

I was thinking I could just use the child_process module and call down to curl myself, but I wanted to check here first in case others are using a better solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that exist a module maybe a bit immature but could help you.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/krb5

Its a native binding for kerberos library

It is able to generate SPNEGO tokens

```
npm install krb5
```